# Get random number in int64 . (Big number)

Tags: c#

Error:

> $exception {"Value was either too large or too small for an Int32."}   System.OverflowException

My code :

```
Random R = new Random();
if (NUD_1.Value > NUD_2.Value)
    return;
int v = R.Next((int)NUD_1.Value ,(int)NUD_2.Value);
    Label_generate2.Text = v.ToString();
```

I want generate number . but when i put a big number it givesme this error .
NUD are the Numeric up downs .

Comment: The error message is pretty clear.  `Random(int, int)` [only works with 32bit integers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx).  You pass 2 `Int32` 's and it returns an `Int32`

Comment: So there isnt any way? How can i get bigger number than is the biggest int32 number . i want like 15 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All what you have to do is to declare:

```
Int64 NUD_1Value = NUD_1.Value;
Int64 NUD_2Value = NUD_2.Value;
```

Then use NUD_1Value instead of NUD.1Value

It will work

---

EDIT:

Check the below. It worked for me:

```
    Random R = new Random();

    double NUD_1Value = 1;
    double NUD_2Value = 999999999999999; //15-digit number

    var next = R.NextDouble();

    double v = NUD_1Value + (next * (NUD_2Value - NUD_1Value));

    MessageBox.Show(v.ToString());
```

Comment: works max with 14 digits . when i do 15 digits this error comes . +  $exception {"'minValue' cannot be greater than maxValue.\r\nParameter name: minValue"} System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: After Edit : Nice this Works . Thank you :)

Comment: I wrote a Test Method and saw this returns Redundant values. Copy these lines and test yourself:  [TestMethod]
        public void TestRand64()
        { Int64 rnum = 0; HashSet<Int64> hs = new HashSet<long>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) { rnum = GetInt64RandomNumber();
                Assert.AreNotEqual(0, rnum); Assert.AreEqual(15, rnum.ToString().Length);
                if (!hs.Contains(rnum)) { hs.Add(rnum); }
                else
                { Console.Write(rnum + " : " + hs.Count.ToString());                    Assert.Fail(); } } }

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
long v = (long)Math.Round(NUD_1.Value + R.NextDouble() * ((double)NUD_2.Value - (double)NUD_1.Value));
```

Comment: The NUD are not double but decimal . it doesnt work .

Comment: I forgot to cast the decimal to double first. I have modified the code to include this.